# When on a meta site, how can you return to the main Stack Overflow site (or whatever site you came from)?

Tags: support, user-experience, navigation

Too many times I've caught myself falling down a Meta rabbit hole, and not being able to get back (quickly) without putting `stackoverflow.com` in my address bar.

I figure there should be a little button for returning to the site you came from. I wrote a userscript for one on SO, and I have used it quite a bit.

Shouldn't this be in the standard website?

Comment: Click the SO icon at top right and there is a link right there.

Comment: In addition to the (at least) two links provided to the main site in the topbar dropdowns (in the help and site switcher dropdowns), going "back" is a function of your browser. If you right-click in on your browser's "back" button (at least in Chrome and Firefox), then you will see a drop-down of your recent pages for that tab. You can then select the one you want to return to, which can be the exact page on the Stack Overflow main site from which you navigated to Meta.

Comment: Also, you could just open the original meta site link in a new tab to start your meta excursion. Then, when you're done with your Meta rabbit hole, just close that tab and you're right back to where you started from.

Comment: It's the Stack Overflow way. Have unnamed buttons with an ambiguous icon and list a good many things under them. The bookmarks toolbar of your browser is way more efficient for quick links.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get from a meta site to its parent site by opening the "Help Center and other Resources" dropdown at the top right of any page and clicking on "Back to <main site>".

[image: Screenshot of Help -> Back to Stack Overflow in the meta top menu of Meta Stack Overflow]

You can also click the Stack Exchange logo to the right of that and navigate between sites there.